# run collector with Eclipse IDE

Tags: source-code

please did someone know how to use eclipse to run or test Collector ,or metrics using eclipse IDE,how to run
https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/network-health/metrics/collector,

Answer (score 0):

You need OpenJDK properly installed on your system, then just run it as a Java application with the corresponding file containing `main()` function implementation. The CollecTor is basically a Java application you can extend or use as it is.